# Cannot Create/Modify Access Point Names in Mobile Network Settings - Huawei G700 - Android 4.2.1

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, mobile-data, huawei, apn

I am trying to edit settings of *APN (Access Point Names)* according to provided guidelines by cellular company to be able to use 3G internet on my Huawei Ascend G700 running on Android 4.2.1.

Whenever I select any item from the default list of *APN* in *Mobile Network Settings* and then try to update and save any field, the whole item gets disappeared from the APN list.

Similarly while trying to create new APN, I provide all the fields and then hit the Save button, the new item doesn't get added to the APN list. No error is shown in this process.

Note: The SIM is inserted and working fine i.e., I can send/receive text messages, make/receive calls using the SIM. I've also asked the provider to send me a message for auto-configuration: when I receive and execute that, it says "internet settings already configured" – but the APN settings are not same like the cellular company 3G internet settings (so it seems auto-configuration has the very same issue of changes not being applied).

**EDIT:**
I navigate to *Settings > About Phone > Status* and observed that there is no info about Mobile Network i.e., *Network, Signal Strength, Mobile Network Type, Service State, Roaming* and *Mobile Network State*.

Comment: I've integrated that with your question as well – and unfortunately am out of ideas now. It *might* be an error in your ROM (e.g. the corresponding configuration file was accidentally made read-only, so changes cannot be written). Have you contacted Huawei support yet with that? Maybe an update could solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I try to contact Huawei support and see what they say.

Comment: Good luck – and please don't forget to keep us posted (or to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) if solved ;)

Comment: Sure, I will post answer if I find any..